# Drive Opera with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, opera

I added to my environment variable

```
SELENIUM_SERVER_JAR = C:\selenium_drivers\selenium-server-standalone.jar
```

Which I downloaded here http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.46/

Python script:

```
from selenium import webdriver

webdriver.Opera()
```

Output:

```
13:37:37.906 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
13:37:38.104 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 25.45-b02
13:37:38.104 INFO - OS: Windows 8 6.2 x86
13:37:38.132 INFO - v2.46.0, with Core v2.46.0. Built from revision 87c69e2
13:37:38.269 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
13:37:38.275 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
13:37:38.630 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:53024/wd/hub
13:37:38.631 INFO - Selenium Server is up and running
13:37:47.892 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{browserName=opera, javascriptEnabled=true, version=, platform=ANY}]])
13:37:47.907 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{browserName=opera, javascriptEnabled=true, version=, platform=ANY}]
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit) 2.43.0.0
Listening on port 43192
13:37:51.090 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{browserName=opera, javascriptEnabled=true, version=, platform=ANY}]]
```

I was expecting jar to have everything defined, why do I get Driver class not found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your question it looks like you are using an old driver for Opera version 12 and older.  Assuming that you're trying to use the most recent version of Opera you'll want to use the driver available at the following site:  [OperaChromiumDriver](https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver)

The site lists sample python code which I have confirmed works on my machine to open and drive Opera:  [Python Examples for OperaChromiumDriver](https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/tree/master/examples)

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome import service


webdriver_service = service.Service('C:\\Users\\Kris\\Downloads\\WinPython-32bit-2.7.9.2\\operadriver.exe')
webdriver_service.start()

driver = webdriver.Remote(webdriver_service.service_url, webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.OPERA)

driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
input_txt = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
input_txt.send_keys('operadriver\n')

time.sleep(5) #see the result
driver.quit()
```

**EDIT:**
Looking into the change logs for selenium it looks like support for Presto-based Operas was discontinued after 2.45 which is why you're getting the error messages:[CHANGELOG](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/java/CHANGELOG)

Answer (score 3):

The code below worked for me on the following setup. Hope this helps.

- Python: 3.4.0
- Opera: 42.0.2393.94
- Selenium: 3.0.2
- ChromeDriver: 2.27.440174

  ```
  import os

  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common import desired_capabilities
  from selenium.webdriver.opera import options

  _operaDriverLoc = os.path.abspath('E:\\Envs\\PySelEnv\\selserver\\chromedriver.exe')  # Replace this path with the actual path on your machine.
  _operaExeLoc = os.path.abspath('E:\\Program Files\\Opera\\42.0.2393.94\\opera.exe')   # Replace this path with the actual path on your machine.

  _remoteExecutor = 'http://127.0.0.1:9515'
  _operaCaps = desired_capabilities.DesiredCapabilities.OPERA.copy()

  _operaOpts = options.ChromeOptions()
  _operaOpts._binary_location = _operaExeLoc

  # Use the below argument if you want the Opera browser to be in the maximized state when launching. 
  # The full list of supported arguments can be found on http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/
  _operaOpts.add_argument('--start-maximized')   

  self._browserDriver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = _operaDriverLoc, chrome_options = _operaOpts, desired_capabilities = _operaCaps)
  ```

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\abc\\Projects\\TestProject\\operadriver.exe')

driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

/*

Just give the location of operadriver.exe ... as above It will open Opera browser... instead of chrome Browser

---

you can download opera driver here : https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver

*/

Answer (score 0):

I use [webdriver_manager package](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/) to drive Opera with selenium.

Installation:

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

Set up:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.opera import OperaDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Opera(executable_path=OperaDriverManager().install())
```

Use:

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```