# Selenium Library, 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, selenium

Consider the following code

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.opera()
```

The following error shows up

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Path/File", line 10, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.opera()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: Your code tries to call the `selenium.webdriver.opera` module as a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case is relevant here, provided your environment is setup correctly you want to call:

`driver = webdriver.Opera()`

Unfortunately it seems you'll need to do some work on setting up your environment to make this work, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31055124/drive-opera-with-selenium-python) answer or follow the link in the exception.