# Controling Opera by Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, opera

I would like to operate Opera by Python + Selenium automatically.

By reference to URL below, I wrote a script below.

[Drive Opera with selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31055124/drive-opera-with-selenium-python)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome import service


webdriver_service = service.Service('/usr/bin/opera')         

webdriver_service.start()

capabilities = { 'operaOptions': { 'debuggerAddress': "localhost:1212" }}

browser = webdriver.Remote(webdriver_service.service_url, webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.OPERA)

response = browser.get('https://www.facebook.com/')
```

By this script, Opera is launched but facebook page does not open.

How should I fix? Please help me.

Settings are below.

Ubuntu 16.04,
Python 3.5.2,
Selenium 3.6.0,
Opera 49.0

Answer (score 0):

```
capabilities = { 'operaOptions': { 'debuggerAddress': "localhost:1212" }}
```

Since you're setting this, I assume you need this to access the network. But, you didn't set it to the webdriver capabilities

```
capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.OPERA
capabilities ['operaOptions'] = { 'debuggerAddress': "localhost:1212" }
browser = webdriver.Remote(webdriver_service.service_url, capabilities)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple and easy way to do it:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Opera()
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com")
# make sure 'operadriver.exe' is in the same folder as your script
```

In case having problems locating opera binary:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location ="<your opera executable directory>"
driver = webdriver.Opera(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com")
# make sure 'operadriver.exe' is in the same folder as your script
```