# Python - Access React Props using Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, selenium

Note: Can be any solution, selenium seems like the most likely tool to solve this.

Imgur has albums, the image links of the albums are stored in (a React element?) `GalleryPost.album_image_store._.posts.{ALBUM_ID}.images` (thanks to [this guy](https://spapas.github.io/2016/06/27/download-imgur-album-images/) for figuring this out).

Using [React DevTools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi) extension for chrome I can see this array of image links, but I want to be able to access this from a python script.

Any ideas how?

P.s. I don't know much at all about react, so please excuse my if this is a stupid question or for possibly using incorrect terminology.

Here's the album I've been working with: https://i.stack.imgur.com/545pu.jpg

## Implemented Solution:

Huge thanks to [Eduard Florinescu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1577343/eduard-florinescu) for working with me to figure all this out. Didn't know hardly anything about selenium, how to run javascript in selenium, or any commands I could use.

Modifying some of his code, I ended up with the following.

```py
from time import sleep

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


# Snagged from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/480227
def rmdupe(seq):
    # Removes duplicates from list
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    return [x for x in seq if not (x in seen or seen_add(x))]


chrome_options = Options()  
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  

prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images":2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.set_window_size(1920, 10000)
driver.get("https://i.stack.imgur.com/545pu.jpg")


links = []
for i in range(0, 10):  # Tune as needed
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    for div in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'image post-image'}):
        imgs = div.find_all('img')
        for img in imgs:
            srcs = img.get_attribute_list('src')
            links.extend(srcs)
        sources = div.find_all('source')
        for s in sources:
            srcs = s.get_attribute_list('src')
            links.extend(srcs)
    links = rmdupe(links)  # Remove duplicates
    driver.execute_script('window.scrollBy(0, 750)')
    sleep(.2)

>>> len(links)
# 36 -- Huzzah! Got all the album links!
```

Notes:

- Creates a headless chrome instance, so the code can be implemented in
  a script or potentially a larger project.
- I used BeautifulSoup because it's a bit easier to work with and I was
  having some issues with finding elements and accessing their values
  using selenium (likely due to inexperience).
- Set the display size to be really "tall" so more image links are
  loaded at once.
- Disabled images in chrome browser settings to stop
  the browser from actually downloading the images (all I need are the
  links).
- Some links are .mp4 files and are rendered in html as `video`
  elements with `<source>` tags contained inside which contain the
  link. The portion of code starting with `sources =
  div.find_all('source')` is there to make sure no album links are
  lost.

Comment: Can you add link to that page?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @MarioNikolaus Any imgur album will work. Here's an example: https://imgur.com/a/JNzjB.

Comment: At first glance, you could retrieve the links using an XPath (`//div[@class="post-images"]//img`) and doing `get_attribute('src')`, but the thing is the DOM changes as you scroll down... at least it's a start. :P

Comment: @Mangohero1 Exactly the problem I'm running into. Being able to access the react components would solve the problem, but I can't find any way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to know any framework to automate any page. You need to just access the DOM and you can do that with selenium and python. But sometimes some simple Vanilla JavaScript helps.

To get those links you  can try and paste this in console:

```
images_links =[]; images = document.querySelectorAll("img"); for (image of images){images_links.push(image.src)} console.log(images_links)
```

Also the selenium with python and the above JS snippet is:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://imgur.com/a/JNzjB")
for i in range(0,7): # here you will need to tune to see exactly how many scrolls you need
  driver.execute_script('window.scrollBy(0, 2000)')

sleep(2)
list_of_images_links=driver.execute_script('images_links =[]; images = document.querySelectorAll("img"); for (image of images){images_links.push(image.src)} return images_links;')
list_of_images_links
```

[image]

### Update:

you don't need selenium just paste this in an Opera console (see that you enable multiple Downloads) and voila:

```
document.body.style.zoom=0.1; images=document.querySelectorAll("img"); for (i of images) { var a = document.createElement('a'); a.href = i.src; console.log(i); a.download = i.src; document.body.appendChild(a); a.click(); document.body.removeChild(a); }
```

same thing beautified for reading:

```
document.body.style.zoom=0.1;
images = document.querySelectorAll("img");
for (i of images) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = i.src;
    console.log(i);
    a.download = i.src;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
}
```

### Update 2 Opera webdriver

```
import os
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common import desired_capabilities
from selenium.webdriver.opera import options

_operaDriverLoc = os.path.abspath('c:\\Python27\\Scripts\\operadriver.exe')  # Replace this path with the actual path on your machine.
_operaExeLoc = os.path.abspath('c:\\Program Files\\Opera\\51.0.2830.34\\opera.exe')   # Replace this path with the actual path on your machine.

_remoteExecutor = 'http://127.0.0.1:9515'
_operaCaps = desired_capabilities.DesiredCapabilities.OPERA.copy()

_operaOpts = options.ChromeOptions()
_operaOpts._binary_location = _operaExeLoc

# Use the below argument if you want the Opera browser to be in the maximized state when launching.
# The full list of supported arguments can be found on http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/
_operaOpts.add_argument('--start-maximized')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = _operaDriverLoc, chrome_options = _operaOpts, desired_capabilities = _operaCaps)


driver.get("https://imgur.com/a/JNzjB")
for i in range(0,7): # here you will need to tune to see exactly how many scrolls you need
  driver.execute_script('window.scrollBy(0, 2000)')

sleep(4)
driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom=0.1")
list_of_images_links=driver.execute_script('images_links =[]; images = document.querySelectorAll("img"); for (image of images){images_links.push(image.src)} return images_links;')
list_of_images_links
driver.execute_script('document.body.style.zoom=0.1; images=document.querySelectorAll("img"); for (i of images) { var a = document.createElement("a"); a.href = i.src; console.log(i); a.download = i.src; document.body.appendChild(a); a.click(); document.body.removeChild(a); }')
```

Comment: Tried the selenium portion myself, but it doesn't return all the links in the album. As your screenshot shows, it only returns 4 links, though there are 36 in that album. At least it's consistent, I got the exact same links back as you did.

Comment: The reason it's not getting all the links is because imgur dynamically loads the images based on the scroll position. If you scroll all the way down, you'll only see the last 4 images, hence why only 4 were returned. Is there a way to get all the images that have been loaded instead of the images currently in the html source? This is why I was hoping for a way to query the react props.

Comment: I see that, is a tricky thing, I will try to look why because if I paste `images = document.querySelectorAll("img");` in console after I do the scroll it gets all elements, I think it has some sort of protection

Comment: It gets only the stuff that are in the view, If I zoom out it gets more

Comment: What % do you set the zoom to? Could you possibly put it all together in your answer?

Comment: I was on an opera browser I see that chrome still protects, if I use `document.body.style.zoom=0.1` is about driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom=0.1")

Comment: I will try with opera driver it's a chrome thing, if you wait a bit I didn't use operadriver before

Comment: No problem, take your time. Do you by chance know of any way to access a react prop from javascript? If I could get access to `GalleryPost.album_image_store._.posts.JNzjB.images` I could get all the image links

Comment: @BobsBurgers I don't know. but doesn't the react code get obfuscated and minimized when deployed, hmmm i better look into the opera thing rather than search for reverse engineering

Comment: I think is a chrome thing that only sources 4 images I see on both opera browser and chromium the js bit loads all the images

Comment: Not sure. Following [this guys article](https://spapas.github.io/2016/06/27/download-imgur-album-images/) that I linked in the question shows you how to access the react components. However, neither he nor I have been able to figure out how to access the react components in pure javascript (withou the need for the react devtools extension)

Comment: Great! Could you update your answer with your solution? Also, what opera webdriver version are you using (is it opera webdriver using blink?)

Comment: @BobsBurgers 
Then you don't need selenium just paste this in an Opera console (see that you enable multiple Downloads) and voila:

`document.body.style.zoom=0.1;
images=document.querySelectorAll("img");
for (i of images) {
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = i.src;
console.log(i);
a.download = i.src;
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
document.body.removeChild(a);
}`

Works for me I tested it

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to confuse. I want to do this in a python script. I was simply giving his article as reference so you could see where the image links were stored. If I used selenium with an Opera driver, could I run that code in an execute_script to get all the images (figured I'd ask since I don't have an opera webdriver installed atm).

Comment: @BobsBurgers It shoud work, I am still looking on the opera thing since opera webdriver is not that  straingt forward and update the answer

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate it. Currently banging my head against the wall trying to get opera webdriver working on debian 8....

Comment: Same on windows it seems that opera support sucks and the  only guy working for it quit
https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/issues/27

Did you try the code in console works for you ?

Comment: I will look once more into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31055124/drive-opera-with-selenium-python on how to make opera work and then if it doesn't  give up.

Comment: @BobsBurgers I managed to make opera driver work is messy on Opera driver sees more than 4 images but seems still not all it seems that imgur detects webdriver I don't know what to do at this point I can do no further

Comment: @BobsBurgers updated with the opera code but still problems I think this nut is hard, it gets into  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41220267/1577343